ParsingReader unable to read a file using reader.read function
I am trying to extract the content from a file and using Apache Tika ParsingReader to read that file.
Now, when i am trying to extract content.
I was using Apache Tika version 2.3.0, there it was reading that document as special characters.

Then I upgraded to 2.9.2 version, it reads that document as blank.


Please link to the source file and add your code. Btw I don't really understand the problem, you're not telling what you are expecting to happen. Both screenshots show useless output.
